Как во flutter сделать flexbox?
Как сделать, чтобы заказы отображались нормально, как на примере? Flex не дал ожидаемых результатов, возможно я как то не так его использовал.
код: https://github.com/kiri4usn/w/blob/main/kitchenTablet.dart
Вопрос, возможно простой, но и я, и chatgpt уже с ума сходим. Занимаюсь flutter от силы дня 4.



Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! Мы заметили, что ваш вопрос требует некоторых уточнений. Прежде чем его опубликовать, рекомендуем ознакомиться с справкой о том, как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Пробовали вместо GridView (это же просто таблица и, как вижу по скрину, она стравляется со своей работой) использовать Wrap?

Wrap немного не то что нужно, но спасибо за наводку, он мне еще пригодится в этом проекте)

Нашел решение в flutter_staggered_grid_view

пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
